# SQL server insert date with check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table with date and constraint

```
Create Table GAMES
(
Ateam varchar(255),
Bteam varchar(255),
Date_play DATETIME Check(Date_play>=1/1/2010 and Date_play<=12/31/2014),
CONSTRAINT Game_PK PRIMARY KEY(Ateam,Bteam),
)
```

It turns out my format in Date_play is not correct, when I insert data into it, it shows error on it. Any problem please?

Update: JChao's answer solve it, thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the date in the check in quotes fixes the issue.

```
Create Table GAMES
(
    Ateam varchar(255),
    Bteam varchar(255),
    Date_play DATETIME Check(Date_play>='1/1/2010' and Date_play<='12/31/2014'),
    CONSTRAINT Game_PK PRIMARY KEY(Ateam,Bteam),
)
```

Here's what the expression looks like if you don't put the quotes

```
([Date_play]>=((1)/(1))/(2010) AND [Date_play]<=((12)/(31))/(2014))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I fix my check now please? I try to drop the check but I didn't name it before so what to put after "Drop constraint "please?

Comment: In SSMS you can see the name of the constraint if you expand the table and then constraints in Object Explorer. Or just DROP the table and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using DATETIME which is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

It looks like you want to be using DATE

DATE is YYYY-MM-DD